# How to only include Bootstrap Popover functionality?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, popover

how can I only include the popover functionality from Twitter Bootstrap? I only want to use popovers in my app and do not want to include any of the other features of Bootstrap.

I've included the following: `src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"`

However none of the popover functions/methods are executed/recognized in my app when I test.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: show your work or code

Comment: Are you including jQuery before you include bootstrap.js? Are there any errors in your console?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll need to include `jquery.js` and `bootstrap.js`, you can skip `bootstrap.css` but your popover will need to be styled. You can use your browsers dev tools to see the popover classes that need to be styled.

HTML:

```
<p>Popover Demo</p>

<a href="#" id="example" rel="popover"
   data-content="This is the body of Popover"
   data-original-title="Demo">pop
</a>
```

JS:

```
$(function () {
    $('#example').popover();
});
```

[CODEPEN DEMO](http://codepen.io/Gothburz/pen/RWqWeE)